# sort an $array of ints by repetition and remove repetitions

Tags: php, sorting, no-duplicates

i need to do this in php
lets say i have `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,9,9,9,9,9]`
i would like `[1,5,9,2,3,4]`

but my situation its a bit different, it's result from a mysql query

i have only an asociative atribute 'id_deseada', so i do now

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
         $t = $row['id_deseada'];
 }
```

so instead of that, i guess i'd have to do domething like the first example; sort $result ordered by times of repetition and maybe beetter in a new array with a new field 'count' ?

This all begins because of this query:

SELECT articles.id as id_deseada,tags.* FROM articles,tags WHERE tags.id_article = articles.id AND tags.name IN ('name one','name two','form search inputs','...)

the problem is that returns one result for every tag and i want on result for every article..

Comment: Why not solve (as least part) of this problem in the SQL query itself?

Comment: cause i'm nod very good at mysql, i'll post the query then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, generate the value array like this:

```
$vals = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
         $vals[] = $row['id_deseada'];
}
```

Then, [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php):

```
$valCounts = array_count_values($vals);
arsort($valCounts);
$result = array_keys($valCounts);
```

Comment: i'll try and let you know.. but one question, then can i do $result[id_deseada], oor i  just go for a 'for' and $result[$i] ?

Comment: The latter, $result will be [1,5,9,2,3,4] in your example.

Comment: ok, got it working with no repetitions! cheers! but the order is the opposite (1 is the last one)

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet. You're right, updated to reverse the order: Use aRsort instead of asort.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it using an SQL query. For example, we have this table:

```
create table lol (id_deseada int);
insert into lol values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),(9),(9),(9),(9),(9);
```

You can select the `id_deseada`'s from the database sorting by repetitions by using grouping and ordering.

```
SELECT id_deseada FROM lol
GROUP BY id_deseada
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Result: 1, 5, 9, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: i'll try and let you know, gracias!